# React-navigation: how to have different headerBackTitles within a single StackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am using react-navigation for my react-native app. I have read the docs on [headerBackTitle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headerbacktitle), but I can't figure out how to set different `headerBackTitle` for navigating from different screens in the stack.

When navigating from **EditProfile** to **MyProfile**, I want the headerBackTitle: to say `Cancel`.

When navigating from **Comments** to **MyProfile**, I want the headerBackTitle to say `Go back`.

Currently, going from both **Comments** and **EditProfile** to **MyProfile** say `Cancel`. How do I accomplish this?

```
const MyProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  MyProfile: {
    screen: profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "My Profile",
      headerBackTitle: 'Cancel'
    }
  },
  Comments: { 
    screen: comments, 
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Comments"
    },
  },
  EditProfile: {
    screen: editProfile,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Edit Profile"
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: do you want change headerbackTitle for iOS or anything else?

Comment: @Tanveerbyn it should work for both iOS and Android

Comment: When navigate to the screen profile, can you try to set the screen where you are coming from (comments or editProfile) like :

```navigation.navigate("profile", {"fromScreen": "editProfile", ...})
navigation.navigate("profile", {"fromScreen": "comments", ...})
```

And in your stack, profile option, you inject the navigation props like :

```navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => { return { headerBackTitle: navigation.state.params.fromScreen === "comments" ? "Go back" : "cancel"  }  }
```

It's just an idea, i haven't tested it before.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, is by making your own header, like so

> Comments.js

```
class Comments extends React.Component{
 render(){
  return(
     <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(null)}>Go Back</Text>
        <Text>Comments</Text>
      </View>
     </View>
     )
    }
   }
```

> EditProfile.js

```
class Comments extends React.Component{
     render(){
      return(
         <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(null)}>Cancel</Text>
            <Text>Edit Profile</Text>
          </View>
         </View>
         )
        }
       }
```